# Solving integral involving Dirac delta function i.e$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e ^{\delta(x)} dx$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I know some properties of Dirac-delta function specially those which are useful for integration involving these functions such as
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

But I am stuck in this (below) integral and don't know how to proceed further or which property should we use?

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e ^{\delta(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

How to solve this problem?

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you define $e^\delta$?

Comment: @Jacky Chong $$\delta(t) $$ is an impulse function !

Comment: @user215805 That's not saying much. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @Jacky Chong- please check this  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function%23Definitions&ved=2ahUKEwiRodK7oPruAhVBaCsKHf1vBgsQygQwI3oECD4QBg&usg=AOvVaw26TSOu2-fuo-cCg_vlk_D2

Comment: @user215805 But that is heuristic definition of $\delta$. In math we need things to be rigorously defined. The Dirac $\delta$ is rigorously defined as a functional on the space of continuous functions. What Jacky Chong is pointing out (as I understand it) is that you would need to first rigorously define $e^{\delta (t)}$ before a meaningful answer could be given. It is *not* good enough to say that $$\delta (t) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} +\infty, & t = 0, \\ 0, & \text{elsewhere}. \end{matrix} \right.$$

Comment: @JackyChong Mathematically that definition makes no sense at all.... The only definition of $\delta$ I have seen physicists use, which makes sense, is as the limit of an approximate identity for the convolution.

Comment: @N.S. You are talking to the wrong person.

Comment: @User8128 but it must also follow one more constraint that is -$$ \int_{t=-\infty}^\infty {\delta(t)} dt =1 $$

Comment: @user215805 Mathematically, if $\delta$ is a function with  $\delta(t)=0$ for all $t \neq 0$, then the integral is zero no matter what $\delta(0)$ is. So the extra constraint makes no sense mathematically.

Comment: You still haven't made precise what $\int e^{\delta(t)}dt$ is even supposed to mean.

Comment: @N.S. You forgot that $e^0=1$

Comment: @Anixx I am talking about the definition of $\delta$, not about the integral. And, $e^0=1$ would be relevant here ONLY if $\delta$ would be a function, but my point is that the function definition of $\delta$ makes no sense.

Comment: @Anixx How did you arrive at that integral?

Answer (score 0):

The expression is not defined. However, we can certainly say that the integral does not converge if we define $\delta$ through approximations.

We will use a Lorentz-curve
$$\delta_\varepsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}{\frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}}.$$
This function has a narrow maximum at $x=0$, the width is
$\sqrt {\epsilon }\to 0$ and the hight
$\frac{1}{\sqrt {\epsilon }}\to \infty$. For all $\varepsilon$ the area below the function is $1$.
As we choose $\varepsilon\to0$, $\delta_\varepsilon(x)$ tends to $\delta(x)$. Now we can evaluate
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{\pi}\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}{\frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x > \operatorname{PV} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{\pi}\lim\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}{\frac{\varepsilon}{x^2+\varepsilon^2}}}\,\mathrm{d}x,$$
which is not the exact same thing as your integral but it now at least makes  a little bit more sense. As you can see I put another integral as an inequality there. The $\operatorname{PV} $ is the Cauchy principal value. So our $x$ does not take values anymore at the "critical point" zero. This integral becomes
$$\operatorname{PV} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{\pi}\cdot0}\,\mathrm{d}x = \operatorname{PV} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}1\,\mathrm{d}x\to\infty.$$
This integral is smaller than our original integral and tends to $\infty$, which means that our first integral diverges too.

Comment: Can you explain some of the steps through which you got that result?

Comment: How are you even defining the integral?

Comment: @runway44 I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The integral does not converge. $\delta(x)=0$ everywhere, except at zero. $e^0=1$. This means, the function under the integral is equal to $1$ nearly everywhere. Regardless of what happens at $0$, the integral diverges.

Comment: Does this answer assume $\delta$ is a function? (It isn't.)

Comment: @runway44 except at zero, it behaves like a function.

Comment: Eh. I'm a little irked by everyone pretending like $\int e^\delta$ means something without any rigorous definition...

Comment: @runway44 this integral diverges, for instance, on the interval $\int_1^\infty e^{\delta(t)}dt$. If interval diverges on one range, it diverges on the whole real line.

Comment: @runway44 I think you are correct, earlier I thought it makes sense that integral diverges but then how we define this integral mathematically!

Comment: I feel there can be an answer which highlights on that.

Comment: In order to use the phrase "this integral," of course, there has to be an integral to talk about in the first place, and in order for $\int \exp\delta(t)dt$ to actually be an integral, you are interpreting $\delta(t)$ as a function that is $0$ everywhere (and define $\delta(0)$ to be any number, it doesn't matter, although you can't define it to be "$\infty$"). That is reasonable given OP might not really understand what $\delta$ is, but I still think it's important to highlight this isn't technically talking about $\delta(t)$, only something like it.

Comment: @runway44 it is absolutely safe to consider $\delta(x)=0$ at $(1,+\infty)$

Comment: No, it is not. $\delta$ is NOT a function.

Comment: @N.S. on $x\ne0$ it is a function.

Comment: @Anixx That's not what I am saying. One of the basic results in measure theory is that there exists no FUNCTION $f  :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \neq 0$ AND $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(X) d x=1$$ So what the physicist call the Dirac function DOES NOT EXISTS. The so called "extra condition" is similar to saying that we pick a number $a \in (1,2)$ with the extra condition $a^2=2021$. This is nonsense.

Comment: @N.S. Nobody says there is such function $f  :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. So, leave the straw man argument aside. We were talking about $(1,+\infty)$

Comment: @Anixx What is your definition of the $\delta$ function? My point is that you are restricting a function which does not exist to an interval, and arguing that it makes sense here...